# Identifying and deleting duplicate columns in pyspark nested Json dataframe

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have a dataFrame with below schema:

```
 |-- nlucontexttrail: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- agentid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- intent: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- confidence: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- entities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- literal: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- intentname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- intentcandidates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- confidence: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- entities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- literal: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- intentname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modelid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modelversion: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nlusessionid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- usednluengine: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- usednluengine: string (nullable = true)
```

If you all can see the highlighted duplicate columns(**"usednluengine"**), one of them has value as 'None' and other has expected value. Now I want to delete the column which has 'None' value. I am sharing the data as well below , please kindly go through it.

```
[{"agentid":"dispatcher","intent":{"confidence":0.8822699,"entities":[{"id":"duration","values":[{"literal":"2 Sekunden","value":"PT2S"}]},{"id":"date","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"T23:00:00Z"},{"literal":"eins","value":"T23:00:00Z"}]},{"id":"number","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"1"},{"literal":"2","value":"2"},{"literal":"eins","value":"1"}]},{"id":"station","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"eins"},{"literal":"eins","value":"eins"}]},{"id":"number_values","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"1"},{"literal":"eins","value":"1"}]},{"id":"percentage_values","values":[{"literal":"höchsten","value":"100"}]}],"intentname":null,"name":"TV"},"intentcandidates":[{"confidence":0.8822699,"entities":[{"id":"duration","values":[{"literal":"2 Sekunden","value":"PT2S"}]},{"id":"date","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"T23:00:00Z"},{"literal":"eins","value":"T23:00:00Z"}]},{"id":"number","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"1"},{"literal":"2","value":"2"},{"literal":"eins","value":"1"}]},{"id":"station","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"eins"},{"literal":"eins","value":"eins"}]},{"id":"number_values","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"1"},{"literal":"eins","value":"1"}]},{"id":"percentage_values","values":[{"literal":"höchsten","value":"100"}]}],"intentname":null,"name":"TV"}],"modelid":"SVH_STAGING__DISPATCHER","modelversion":13,"nlusessionid":null,"usednluengine":"luis"},{"agentid":"dispatcher","intent":{"confidence":0.140685484,"entities":[{"id":"duration","values":[{"literal":"2 Sekunden","value":"PT2S"}]},{"id":"date","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"T23:00:00Z"},{"literal":"eins","value":"T23:00:00Z"}]},{"id":"number","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"1"},{"literal":"2","value":"2"},{"literal":"eins","value":"1"}]},{"id":"number_values","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"1"},{"literal":"eins","value":"1"}]},{"id":"percentage_values","values":[{"literal":"höchsten","value":"100"}]}],"intentname":null,"name":"TV__SWITCH_CHANNEL"},"intentcandidates":[{"confidence":0.140685484,"entities":[{"id":"duration","values":[{"literal":"2 Sekunden","value":"PT2S"}]},{"id":"date","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"T23:00:00Z"},{"literal":"eins","value":"T23:00:00Z"}]},{"id":"number","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"1"},{"literal":"2","value":"2"},{"literal":"eins","value":"1"}]},{"id":"number_values","values":[{"literal":"eins","value":"1"},{"literal":"eins","value":"1"}]},{"id":"percentage_values","values":[{"literal":"höchsten","value":"100"}]}],"intentname":null,"name":"TV__SWITCH_CHANNEL"}],"modelid":"SVH_STAGING__TV","modelversion":13,"nlusessionid":null,"usednluengine":"luis"}]
```

You may placed the above data in below link to see it in proper format:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Point to be noted is duplicate column which has value as 'None' will not be visible in data but actually it is available in df.printSchema, I want to delete all duplicate columns/nested-columns(which are part of inside struct) from schema , and keep the column which has value. With which I mean **no change in data but change in schema actually**.

Hope I am able to clear my question. If not please comment below for further discussions.